# Study the Convergence of the $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\left (\frac{1}{n}+\frac{\cos (\pi n)}{2n}\right)$

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence

as it's told on the title im asking for the convergence of the $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\left (\frac{1}{n}+\frac{\cos (\pi n)}{2n}\right)$ .
I tried to use the Leibniz's test, but I need the $\cos$ term to be monotonic. I derived it, and the derivative function it's always negative, but i tried to plot the function or give the first values for $n=1,2,3,4$ and it's not monotonic.
I know it converges but I don't know how to prove it.

Thanks for helping

Comment: What does $\cos\left(\pi n \right)$ value for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ ?

Comment: For $n \in \mathbb{N}$ it's $(-1)^n$

Comment: Then combine with the first $\left(-1\right)^n$ it equals $1$. Can you conclude now ? ( minoring for example )

Comment: If you do this you get to $\sum (\frac{(-1)^n}{n}+\frac{1}{2n})$

Comment: And as I explained on a comment below the sum doesn't abs converge so you can't split the terms, splitting the terms it's like rearrange the sum and you can't do that if its not abs convergent

Comment: I did that ? No. However i suggest you consider partial sum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all note that $\cos(n\pi) = (-1)^n$, so we have that:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\left (\frac{1}{n}+\frac{\cos (\pi n)}{2n}\right) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\left (\frac{1}{n}+\frac{(-1)^n}{2n}\right)= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left (\frac{(-1)^n}{n}+\frac{1}{2n}\right)$$

Now as $\frac{(-1)^n}{n}+\frac{1}{2n} = \frac{1 + 2(-1)^n}{2n}$, so for the sum is $\frac{3}{2n}$ for even terms and $\frac{-1}{2n}$ for odd terms. Considering the partial sums we have:

$$S_N = \sum_{n=1}^N (-1)^n\left (\frac{1}{n}+\frac{\cos (\pi n)}{2n}\right) = -\frac 12 + \frac 34 - \frac 16 + \frac{3}{8} - \cdots$$

For two consecutive numbers we have $\frac{3}{4k} - \frac{1}{2(2k-1)} = \frac{6k-3-2k}{4k(2k-1)} = \frac{4k-3}{8k^2 - 4k}$. This means that the partial sums behave like the harmonic series, so it's divergent.

Comment: Would you like to check the inequality $\frac{(-1)^n}n+\frac1{2n}\ge\frac1n$ again?

Comment: agree on Jason comment

Comment: The sign of the inequation is on the other direction

Comment: @Ginger Ooops. I will try to fix it now

Comment: No problem bro!

Comment: @Ginger Is it better now?

Answer (score 0):

$\cos(\pi n)=(-1)^n$, so the sum diverges.

Comment: The sum converges

Comment: How u get to the sum diverges? I mean, if you did it by splitting the sum on two terms u can't do that. The function doesn't abs converges, so you can't rearrange the sum

Comment: @Ginger You don't need to split the infinite sum. You can take partial sum up to $n$ and split, and argue that as $n$ grows the first part tends to a limit while the second part explodes, so that the series does not converge. The answer is correct.

Comment: @Ginger The series diverges.

Answer (score 0):

As has been noted, the series is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ where $a_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{n}+\frac1{2n}$, or
$$a_n=\begin{cases}
-\frac1{2n},&n\text{ odd,}\\
\frac3{2n},&n\text{ even.}\end{cases}$$
If $\{s_n\}$ is the sequence of partial sums, then
$$s_{2n}=\sum_{k=1}^n(a_{2k-1}+a_{2k})=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{4k-3}{4k(2k-1)}.$$
The series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{4k-3}{4k(2k-1)}$ diverges by comparison with the harmonic series, so in particular our original series diverges.

Comment: Ye Jason! Much thanks foe your time  <3

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum \frac {1}{2n} $$ diverges and
$$\sum \frac {(-1)^n}{n} $$ converges as an alternate series.

the sum of a divergent and a convergent series is a divergent series.